# Column names from query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get make a query to return a list of the column names from a query result in postgresql

e.g.

```
SELECT column_name 
  FROM ( 
        SELECT table1.* 
          FROM table1 
               LEFT JOIN table2 
                         ON table1.id = table2.tbl1_id
        )
```

is this possible

I DO NOT WANT THE COLUMNS FROM A SINGULAR TABLE!!! so please dont tell me to do

```
SELECT column_name
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_name = 'table1'
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would ever need to do this? `SELECT *` should [**NEVER** be used in production code](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) anyway, so if you are explicitly listing your columns as you should be, then you will always know the columns being returned. In ad hoc code just query the information_schema on an ad hoc basis to see what columns are in the tables you are querying.

Comment: This might be useful, when you're debugging a lot of `JOIN`s @GarethD

Comment: If you are debugging surely you can just use `SELECT *` along with `LIMIT 1` and you would get the column names as headers in the IDE? And again, the columns should either be explicitly stated, or if using `SELECT *` then why not just query the information_schema for all the tables being selected from?

Comment: Because you need to put more effort in it

Comment: Adding some context to why you want to do this might help some. Aside from dumping your query to a table so you can query the information_schema.columns I don't see you getting what you want.

Comment: If you are running that statement through JDBC you can query the `ResultSetMetaData` for the column names (which can be obtained from the ResultSet)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you would ever need to do this, but it is possible using some of the JSON functions introduced in 9.3.

```
SELECT json_object_keys(row_to_json(t)) FROM
 (SELECT * FROM table1
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.tbl1_id LIMIT 1) t;
```

This will give you the name of every column returned for a single row. Without the `LIMIT` you would get the columns repeated for every row returned. If you wanted to see the values returned as well you can get more complex:

```
WITH t as
  (SELECT * FROM table1
   LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.tbl1_id LIMIT 1)
SELECT json_data.key, json_data.value
FROM t, json_each_text(row_to_json(t)) AS json_data;
```

Both these queries will return all the columns even if they are named the same. If all you want is a list of unique column names, you can utilize hstore:

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore; --Create the extension if you need it.

SELECT akeys(hstore(t)) as array_of_columns
FROM
(SELECT * FROM table1
 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.tbl1id LIMIT 1) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a less hacky way, but I think this should work:

```
create table query_column_sample from (your query where 1=2);
SELECT column_name
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_name = 'query_column_sample'
```

Comment: that's obv not an answer

Comment: Maybe not a perfect one, but I think it satisfies the requirements.

Comment: Not, it's not. It's a workaround. Question was how to `DESCRIBE` temp table, and you suggesting `CREATE TABLE`, so it would stop being temp. That's not answer at all.

Comment: It is hard to tell what the OP wants exactly. If his primary goal is to avoid getting data and his query is too complex to handle with simple queries against information_schema, then this solution can be a help.

Answer (score 0):

Querying tables returns data. Querying the information schema returns metadata. Column names are metadata.

```
SELECT 'table1', column_name
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_catalog = 'database_name'
   AND table_schema  = 'schema_name'
   AND table_name = 'table1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table2', column_name
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_catalog = 'database_name'
   AND table_schema  = 'schema_name'
   AND table_name = 'table2';
```

"schema_name" is probably *public*. But be warned that you can have multiple tables with the same name, as long as they are in different schemas. (You could have "public.table1" and "private.table1".) You can also have multiple tables with the same name in different databases. You need to specify all three values--database name, schema name, table name--to be sure of getting the right data.

If I had to do this in production I'd probably output more data. I'd also probably include the column "ordinal_position", and sort on it. Sorting by "ordinal_position" will order column names as they appear in the current table definition.

```
SELECT table_catalog
     , table_schema
     , table_name 
     , column_name
     , ordinal_position
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_catalog = 'sandbox'
  AND table_schema  = 'public'
  AND table_name IN ('table1', 'table2')
ORDER BY table_catalog
       , table_schema
       , table_name
       , ordinal_position;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable approach I can come up with is to do something like this.  Schema location plays into this, but I'm just posting the basic idea.  SQL doesn't have reflection at run time unless you go and hit meta data tables, which is what you seem to be trying to achieve here.

```
SELECT table1.* 
INTO x
      FROM table1 
           LEFT JOIN table2 
                     ON table1.id = table2.tbl1_id LIMIT 0;

select *
from information_schema.columns
where table_Name = 'x';
```

Also interesting enough while traveling the Internets over lunch I ran into this. Works with PostgreSQL 8.2.0 or higher.

https://github.com/theory/colnames/tree/master/test/sql